# Can I return to Mexico with a passport that expires soon?

Tags: air-travel, passports, mexico, mexican-citizens

I'm traveling to Mexico in May 17th 2016, but my Mexican passport expires in July 19th 2016.

Will I have any problem with it since it expires two month later?

Answer (score 2):

**No**, you will not.  As you are a Mexican citizen, you have the right to enter Mexico and stay there as long as you like, and since your passport is still valid, it's acceptable ID for airlines.

Comment: He might have trouble *leaving* Mexico if the trip to Mexico is short and if he doesn't get a new passport during the trip.

Comment: @phoog Sure, but that's a different issue -- and it wouldn't be Mexico stopping him from leaving, but the destination(/airline) not allowing him to enter.

Comment: Right, but the question is worded broadly enough that this "different issue" is not excluded ("will I have any problem with it...").